# Why must we "change temporary credentials for token credentials" in OAuth?

Tags: oauth, token

Can't the server just "upgrade" the temporary credentials to token credentials and retain the same key and secret?

The client can then start doing authenticated calls right away after the recieving the callback from the server stating that the temporary credentials has been "upgraded".

Of cause if the temporary credentials have not be upgrade (i.e. client doesn't wait for callback) the authenticated call fails.

So the question is why make an extra call to the server after the callback to "exchange" temporary credentials for token credentials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *could* implement OAuth in that way, but as I understand it, separating Request Tokens from Access Tokens does provide an extra layer of security.

From the [Beginner's Guide](http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iii-security-architecture/):

> OAuth includes two kind of Tokens:
>   Request Token and Access Token. Each
>   Token has a very specific role in the
>   OAuth delegation workflow. While
>   mostly an artifact of how the OAuth
>   specification evolved, the two-Token
>   design offers some usability and
>   security features which made it
>   worthwhile to stay in the
>   specification. OAuth operates on two
>   channels: a front-channel which is
>   used to engage the User and request
>   authorization, and a back-channel used
>   by the Consumer to directly interact
>   with the Service Provider. By limiting
>   the Access Token to the back-channel,
>   the Token itself remains concealed
>   from the User. This allows the Access
>   Token to carry special meanings and to
>   have a larger size than the
>   front-channel Request Token which is
>   exposed to the User when requesting
>   authorization, and in some cases needs
>   to be manually entered (mobile device
>   or set-top box).

So, as I understand it, by limiting the Access Token to a channel directly between the consumer (your service) and the provider (the service you're gaining access to), you can obtain a secure Access Token (that is, one the attacker doesn't have) even if the user's machine or the user's network connection to your service is compromised.  If the Request Token were simply upgraded, then anyone sniffing the user's network connection could easily obtain the Request/Access Token, which we'd prefer to keep secret since it can be used (with your consumer token, of course), potentially for a very long time, to access the user's data.  A server-to-server connection is often more secure.

Also, as is pointed out above, this lets you have a much longer key in cases where the Request Token actually has to be typed out by the user (and so is probably very short).

Comment: I didn’t find “Request token” in the modern [The OpenIdConnect 1./OAuth2 documentation](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).
It’s not mentioned in [how is oauth-2-different-from-oauth-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113934/how-is-oauth-2-different-from-oauth-1)
 either.
Did you mean  Authorization code instead of Request token?