# OAuth Spec: why do some implementations return an access_token + access_token_secret and others just an access token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Case in point:

The Facebook `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` endpoint, in handing off a code for an access token, returns the `access_token` and `expires`. Instagram seems to do the same.

On the other hand, the Twitter `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token` returns both an `access_token` and an `access_token secret`.

Subsequently, when accessing Facebook API endpoints, I just send the access_token with the request. On the other hand, accessing Twitter endpoints requires signing the request with the secret as well.

The reason I ask: I'm implementing my own OAuth web app API, and would like to make sure I conform properly to standards. I designed it initially to act like Twitter, but I don't understand why Facebook & Instagram act in the way they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook and Instagram use the OAuth 2.0 protocol whereas Twitter uses the OAuth 1.0a protocol. The posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113934/how-is-oauth-2-different-from-oauth-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643828/whats-the-difference-between-oauth-and-oauth-2-0) may help you understand the differences.