# Using OAuth2 for my own Android app

Tags: android, database, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

Please excuse my stupidity but is it possible to use something like OAuth2 so that users can log into my app securely even though the app doesn't use any features of Facebook or Google+ etc. So simply I just want something to authenticate my users.

My app makes calls to a database server but currently I have no security what-so-ever and I haven't got a clue as to what to even google for. I want to hold encrypted passwords for the users on the database and pass back some kinda of token to say they're now logged in, but I don't know how to go about this and just wondered if there was something more simple?

Comment: This is the same question I am having. I have been looking at OAuth2, but as I understand OAuth is mainly used to allow access to third party consumers (applications) to your own services. So in our case, we are looking for authentication for our own application and not something like what Twitter does. However, that does not mean it is impossible to use OAuth for first party applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a long read in the threads here at stackoverflow. I would recommend having a read through [*this one*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561631/oauth-2-0-benefits-and-use-cases-why). If you read the post, what you are looking for is a two-legged authentication, since you already trust the application (your own) you can trust it with the username and password. So, all you need is to authenticate those with your own database at the server and provide an access token to the user.

Comment: Hey @hishamaus, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error `com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown.` Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151