# PHP's OAuth class (pecl/oauth)

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, oauth

What versions of OAuth is supported by this extension and will I be able to use it to authenticate with both Facebook and Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension only supports OAuth (1). For Facebook which uses OAuth2 you can use a library like this one: https://github.com/quizlet/oauth2-php

When you look at questions like [How is OAuth 2 different from OAuth 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113934/how-is-oauth-2-different-from-oauth-1) you will find that OAuth2 is very much unlike OAuth