# Authenticating REST API clients for just my App

Tags: rest, ssl

What is the best way to authenticate clients that uses my private REST API? I will not be opening this to outside public. Is there a easy and secure way to do this?

Note: I'm running SSL already.  I've looked at HTTP Basic Auth over SSL, but I don't want to ask the user to send the password every time, and it seems not good practice to store the user/pass in the client to be send automatically.

Any ideas or best practices?

Comment: My suggestion is to use api keys, that can be easily revoked and the client can be updated quickly. Any authentication method that the client has such as username and password can be read by anyone who has the client. Look into how google, facebook or twitter secure their apis as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the most adopted authentication approach which is [OAuth](http://oauth.net/)
You select the best suited one between [OAuth 1.0a](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/) and [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/)

Here is a comparison between the above two ways : [How is OAuth 2 different from OAuth 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113934/how-is-oauth-2-different-from-oauth-1)

Answer (score 0):

There are several levels to implement security / authentication in RESTful services:

- **Basic authentication**. Username and password are sent for each call within the `Authentication` header encoded with based 64.
- **Token-based authentication**. This implies a dedicated authentication resource that will provide temporary token based on credentials. Once received there is no need to use again credentials since this resource also gives a refresh token to a new authentication token when the previous expired.
- **OAuth2**. It provides different flows according to the use cases. It allows to let the end user to authenticate through a third-part provider (google, facebook, ...). The application doesn't manage username / password (and even know the password). The drawback of this technology is that it provides high-level hints and it's not so simple to implement.

Here are some links that could provide you some additional hints:

- Implementing authentication with tokens for RESTful applications - https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/
- OAuth2 flows - http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2013/03/10/understanding-oauth2/

Hope it helps you,
Thierry