# Spring security 5.*.* support for OAuth 1.0

Tags: spring, spring-security

As you all know spring-social apparently was abandoned (it was announced in 2018). The problem is, Spring Security provides ready to go configuration for OAuth 2.0 (googled it for almost 1 hour). So my question is, what should I do, if I would like to use twitter? Should I use spring-social for this (As legacy code) or is there some way to configure OAuth 1.0 in Spring Security 5.x.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer on my own question [Spring Boot OAuth 2.0 and OAuth 1.0a clients in same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633210/spring-boot-oauth-2-0-and-oauth-1-0a-clients-in-same-app), which led me to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples

Also, I think, I will use my legacy code for twitter. It is much easier, then to start working on completely new implementation just because spring social is outdated and there is no normal support for OAuth 1.0.